# Render HTML content in Angular Js like normal variable

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I have to render HTML content using AngularJS, I can do it like so

```
<div ng-bind-html="myHtmlContent"></div>
```

And it works, but the only problem I have is I don't want to render it inside a string, I rather want it to just render it where I want to render it. e.g

```
<div>
<h2>{{page.ttitle}}</h2>
{{myHtmlContent}}
</div>
```

like here, I don't want to add another div, and load myHtmlContent inside. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im afraid you can't, unless you write your custom directive like :

```
<my-direcive></my-directive>
```

or

```
 <my-direcive var="myHtmlContent"></my-directive>
```

You can also put all diectives in one element e.g.

```
<body ng-app="bindHtmlExample" ng-controller="ExampleController" ng-bind-html="myHTML">

</body>
```

This is probably not the best practice but should work.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, this <my-direcive var="myHtmlContent"></my-directive> worked for me.